# How to show HTTP response in Object Choice Field in Blackberry

Tags: http, blackberry, choicefield

I am reading a response from server using this code.

```java
public static String getContentString(HttpConnection Connection) throws IOException
{
    String Entity=null;
    InputStream inputStream;
    inputStream = Connection.openInputStream();//May give network io
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    int c;
    while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) 
    {
         buf.append((char) c);
    }

    //Response Formation            
    try
    {
        Entity = buf.toString();
        return Entity;
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        Entity = null;
        return Entity;
    }

}
```

I need to show this Entity in object choice field.
For example:
suppose i get response Entity=`ThisIsGoingToGood`

then, I need to show below way in object choice drop down list.

- This
- Is
- Going
- To
- Good

Please tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: you getting like "ThisIsGoingToGood" . Then convert this by splitting  text like "This", "Is" ,"Going" ,"To", "Good"  ?. What you mean ?

Comment: @Signare-It is not text file first.It is response in Entity string shown as in code. By splitting text of Entity String.I am trying to show how i need this in object choice field.As "This" should be first choice of choicefield."Is" should be second choice of choicefield and so on.

Comment: **Which** problem are you asking about?  Are you asking how to *split* a string that has no spaces in it?  Are you asking how to update an `ObjectListField` from a background thread, that's requesting HTTP data?

Comment: @Nate yes I am asking that how to split a string which has no spaces coming from http response in Entity.As i know inputStream.read() read character by character.

Comment: @user2218773 first clearly explain your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes:

- The *Camel Case* format of your strings will always **start** with an upper case letter.
- Only one upper case character in a row is used, even if the *word* is an acronym.  For example, "HTTP response" would be written as `"HttpResponse"`.

```java
public static Vector getContentStrings(HttpConnection connection) throws IOException {
    Vector words = new Vector();

    InputStream inputStream = connection.openInputStream();
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    int c;
    while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) 
    {
        char character = (char)c;
        if (CharacterUtilities.isUpperCase(character)) {
            // upper case -> new word
            if (buf.length() > 0) {
                words.addElement(buf.toString());
                buf = new StringBuffer();
            }
        }
        buf.append(character);
    }
    // add the last word
    words.addElement(buf.toString());

    return words;
}
```

Then, you'll have a nice `Vector` full of the choices for your `ObjectChoiceField`.  You can then `insert()` them, as shown in Signare's answer.

**Note:** always remember to close your streams, too.  I've leave it to you to decide when you're really finished with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

With ref from Nate's Answer- try this -

```
ObjectListField ol = new ObjectListField(ObjectListField.ELLIPSIS);
ol.setSize(words.size()); //Where words is the vector 
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
ol.insert(i, words.elementAt(i));
}
add(ol);
```

Comment: Please tell me how to get size and value from "ThisISGoingToGood".